# Looking for a suitable tag-name for the Bitcoin-S library; [bitcoin-s] is too similar to [bitcoin]

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just attempted to tag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73071698/2707792) about the usage of the [Bitcoin-S](https://github.com/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s) library with the new tag [bitcoin-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin-s), but the system does not allow to do this with the message:

> The tag [bitcoin-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin-s) is too similar to [bitcoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin). If you think this new tag should be allowed, discuss it on Meta.

so now I'm looking for better alternatives.

A separate tag might be useful for clearly distinguishing general questions about Bitcoin from the very specific questions about the usage of one particular Bitcoin implementation named "Bitcoin-S".

- A dedicated tag could hold a link to the relevant library-specific documentation, which is crucial for answering the questions (for example, to properly answer the linked question, one would have to look at the signature of one specific method on [this documentation page](https://bitcoin-s.org/api/org/bitcoins/core/protocol/dlc/models/ContractDescriptor%24.html));
- I assume that general language-agnostic answers to [bitcoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin) questions are of little help to the people dealing with specific type checking issues in Bitcoin-S.
- I assume that the average follower of the [bitcoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin)-tag is not interested in extremely specific typing error messages of Bitcoin-S.

My currently favorite alternative to [bitcoin-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin-s) would be [scala-bitcoin-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-bitcoin-s). It might seem a bit redundant, but it would be clearly distinct from [bitcoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin), and it would have the same prefix as some other prominent libraries in the ecosystem, such as, for example:

- [scala-cats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-cats) for the [Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) library
- [scala-gatling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-gatling) for the [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) tool

So, it seems that with [scala-bitcoin-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-bitcoin-s), the Bitcoin-S library would be in good company.

Wdyt?

Comment: Is the differentiation between the two tags relevant to the sample question? is either tag really relevant to the sample question? It looks like a general logic problem in a language that certainly isn't used *only* for that.

Comment: @KevinB It took me several comments and a few minutes to figure out what specific library the question was about. Before I could see the documentation, I couldn't tell for sure whether there is maybe some overloaded version of the method that _should_ be doing what the OP attempted. Before you see the documentation (or source), you can't tell whether it should compile or not. And I think it would be preferable if people who could potentially answer this question would get a more direct link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: _Why_ do developers keep giving their projects such bad names? It's a pain to make tags for them. [bitcoin-s] isn't a good tag name, and probably will attract [bitcoin] questions because people.

Comment: Also can't think of any immediately obvious ways to disambiguate it; `.scala` feels awkward when the `-s` already stands for Scala, and I'm not deep enough in either scala or that library to give anything more useful

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine _"Why do developers keep giving their projects such bad names?"_ - I don't know, you'd have to ask the maintainers of `bitcoin-s`. No idea why they thought that this library name would be searchable. Could you maybe suggest some prefix that would prevent any kind of confusion? Something like `[org.bitcoin-s]` or `[scala-bitcoin-s]` or something like that? (Sorry, didn't read your follow up comment; I think `[scala-bitcoin-s]` would be a bit tautological, but might do the job of holding the link to docs)

Comment: yeah, that's my issue with all the options I can think of. They're all redundant, but I don't think there are any better options, unless the bitcoin-s devs (or powerusers or whatever) indicate the existence of a commonly used second name, but I can't easily see one on the website.

Comment: Plan B is going through with  [scala-bitcoin-s] to take care of the immediate problem, and either pinging bitcoin-s people in a place that makes sense, or letting the tag's existence draw in bitcoin-s people with better ideas than that. It's not optimal, but that's what happens when the names are bad

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I'd go with `[scala-bitcoin-s]`. The [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) tool is tagged as `[scala-gatling]`, the [Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) library is tagged as `[scala-cats]`, I think that `[scala-bitcoin-s]` wouldn't be too surprising.

Comment: Separately, you should find a question that is actually _about_ the library, rather than merely incidentally containing code using it while asking about something entirely unrelated.

Comment: @RyanM It's a question by a user who fails to use the API of a library. In order to answer this question properly, one _really_ needs [this exact documentation page](https://bitcoin-s.org/api/org/bitcoins/core/protocol/dlc/models/ContractDescriptor$.html), and one _really_ needs to see the exact signature of `def fromTLV` method, everything else would be just guessing.

Comment: Alright, I'll take your word for it.  I'm not sufficiently familiar with Scala or the library to judge.  My initial read was that it was familiarity with `Either` that mattered, but that was merely a semi-educated guess.

Comment: There's a `bitcoinjs-lib` for [BitcoinJS](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib).  But then again, that's the name of their github repo.  Which makes The `bitcoin-s-core` answer even more appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm increasingly gravitating towards [scala-bitcoin-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-bitcoin-s).

Taking the name of the library, and then prepending the `<language-name>-` prefix to it, seems like a common approach, at least for the Scala ecosystem, as evidenced by [scala-gatling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-gatling) or [scala-cats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-cats).

Comment: All languages have their way of doing things, so it's not an unreasonable approach. JavaScript frequently has `.js` at the end of their libraries, for instance. Admittedly, this is in the proper names and not just tags on stack. I'd recommend creating [tag:scala-bitcoin-s] for now

Answer (score 0):

[bitcoin-s-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin-s-core)

Just a suggestion, since I noticed that's [what they are using on Gitter](https://gitter.im/bitcoin-s-core/).

Comment: [This page here](https://bitcoin-s.org/docs/core/core-intro) says _"The `core` module is the core [...] functionality of Bitcoin-S"_ - it's only the small secure core part of the library, it's not the entire library. It also seems to me that the gitter channel is for discussions about the internal implementation details of the library, that's why they've appended "-core" to it.